# Approximate probabilities of a binomial random variable using the normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

> A fabrication process is making 8% broken units. Everyday we take 200 units to check how many unites are broken (X). With the normal law as an approximation of the binomial law, find : $$ P (X \le 16)$$ $$P(X=150)$$ $$P(12 \le X \le 20)$$ $$P(X=14)$$

I have a random variable that obey a binomial law with :

$$n = 200 $$
$$p = 0.08$$

I want to approximate it with a normal law. I get :

$$\mu = 200 * 0.08 = 16 $$
$$\sigma^2 = 200 * 0.08( 1 - 0.08) =  14.72$$

I want to find

$$P(X=15) = ?$$

I try this :

$$ 1 - P( X <= 14) $$
$$ 1 - \phi (\frac{14 - 16}{14.72}) $$ 
$$ 1 - \phi(-0.14) $$
$$ 1 - ( 1 - \phi(0.14)) $$
$$ \phi(0.14) $$
$$ 0.55670$$

Which is not the result I should find.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean $P(X>15)$? Because $P(X=15)=0$, as it's a continuous distribution.

Comment: No,  I am really asked to find $ P = ( X = 15) $. But at the beginning I am asked to approximate a binomial by the normal. Maybe, I did not find the right mean and variance. I edit.

Comment: If it comes from a binomial $Y$, then we will have, for not too small $n$, $\Pr(Y=15)\approx \Pr(X\le 15.5)-\Pr(X\le 14.5)$. But it would be helpful to know the original binomial, to see whether the approximation is reasonable. If $n$ is large and $p$ is small a Poisson approximation may be better.

Comment: Now that the question makes sense... the usual way is to approximate $P(X=i)$ by $P(i-1/2<\mu+\sigma Z<i+1/2)$ where $Z$ is standard normal, $\mu=E(X)$ and $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $X$. Can you finish this?

Comment: You didn't "normalize" the variable correctly.  When converting to the standard normal distribution you divide by $\sigma$ itself not $\sigma^2$

Comment: @Did So sorry, I did not use the correction for continuation. 
Thank you very much for your answers guys. I got -1, should I delete ?

Comment: Wait, you cannot compute $P(a<Z<b)$ with $Z$ as in my previous comment? And you cannot transform $P(i-1/2<\mu+\sigma Z<i+1/2)$ into $P(a<Z<b)$ for some well-chosen $(a,b)$?

Comment: @Did Done finally. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the original distribution is $X \sim Binom(n = 20, p = .08).$
Using R (in which the PDF is `dbinom` and the CDF is 'pbinom`), I get exact probabilities as follows:

```
 n = 200;  p = .08
 pbinom(16, n, p)
 ## 0.5660199
 dbinom(150, n, p)
 ## 2.040844e-119
 diff(pbinom(c(11, 30), n, p))
 ## 0.8828718
 sum(dbinom(12:30, n, p))
 ## 0.8828718
 dbinom(14, n, p)
 ## 0.09541156
```

The respective, normal approximations, with continuity corrections, are:

```
 mu = n*p;  sg = sqrt(n*p*(1-p))
 pnorm(16.5, mu, sg)
 ## 0.551844
 diff(pnorm(c(149.5, 150.5), mu, sg))
 ## 0
 diff(pnorm(c(11.5, 30.5), mu, sg))
 ## 0.8795021
 diff(pnorm(c(13.5, 14.5), mu, sg))
 ## 0.09058454
```

This particular binomial distribution, even though skewed, should be reasonably well
approximated by the normal distribution. You can expect almost
two place accuracy. For the continuity correction, see the note
by @AndreNicolas, and the first figure below.

If you want to use standard normal tables,
you need to standardize first, but R software does not require you
to standardize in these problems. Results from tables of standard normal $Z$
will not be quite the same because of rounding errors. Specifically,
$$P(X=14) = P(13.5 \le X \le 14.5) \approx
P\left(\frac{13.5-16}{3.84} < Z < \frac{14.5-16}{3.84}\right)\\
= \Phi(-0.39) - \Phi(-0.65) = 0.1016.$$

Approximations based on $Pois(np)$ are as follows.

```
 ppois(16, mu)
 ## 0.5659624
 dpois(150, mu)
 ## 8.173203e-90
 diff(ppois(c(11, 30), mu))
 ## 0.87244
 sum(dpois(12:30, mu))
 ## 0.87244
 dpois(14, mu)
 ## 0.09301644
```

The figure below shows the exact binomial probabilities (bars),
approximating Poisson probabilities (dots), and the normal density curve
with mean and variance matching those of the binomial distribution.
Vertical dotted lines show the area under the normal curve that
approximates $P(12 \le X \le 20).$

[image]

Note: For a binomial distribution with larger $n$ and smaller $p$, such that the mean remains $\mu = np = 16,$
the Poisson approximation would improve noticeably; the normal perhaps not
changed by much.

[image]

Comment: Very detailed, thank you very much. It helps for the comprehension.

Comment: Excellent. Comprehension of these three distributions and their relationships is important both for theory and practice, so well worth your effort.